# If mouse is clicked then don't execute mouse leave event

Tags: vb.net

Hi I want to show a `Label` for hint so if mouse hover then show `Label` and mouse leave then hide `Label`.
But if mouse click then show label and don't execute leave event, because leave event means hide mouse. So how can I perform it? My code is here.

**Click Event**

```
Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
    control("set")
End Sub
```

**Hover Event**

```
Private Sub Label2_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.MouseHover
    control("show")
End Sub
```

**Leave Event**

```
Private Sub Label2_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.MouseLeave
    control("remove")
End Sub
```

**Control Sub**

```
Public Sub control(ByVal c As String)
    If c = "set" Then
        Label3.Visible = True
    ElseIf c = "show" Then
        Label3.Visible = True
    ElseIf c = "remove" Then
        Label3.Visible = False
    End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `EventHandler` when `Label2` is clicked:

```
Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
    RemoveHandler Label2.MouseLeave, AddressOf Label2_MouseLeave
End Sub
```

Not sure what exaclty is the purpose of the `control`-method...but the code could be reduced to this:

```
Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
    RemoveHandler Label2.MouseLeave, AddressOf Label2_MouseLeave
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.MouseHover
    Label3.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.MouseLeave
    Label3.Visible = False
End Sub
```