# c# winform : How to ignore the event of leaving the mouse after clicking on the label?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

The program practically executes the mouse leave event after the user clicks and leaves the mouse from the control, if I do not want to  run the mouse leave event  when the click is executed.

```
    private void LblNoeMelk_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HoverColor.LblHover(LblNoeMelk);
    }

    private void LblNoeMelk_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        LeaveColor.LblLeave(LblNoeMelk);
    }

    private void LblNoeMelk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HoverColor.LblHover(LblNoeMelk);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424595/if-mouse-is-clicked-then-dont-execute-mouse-leave-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing @Saeed solution in code-

```
bool isLabelClicked = false;

private void LblNoeMelk_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HoverColor.LblHover(LblNoeMelk);
    }

    private void LblNoeMelk_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(isLabelClicked ==true)
        {
              isLabelClicked = false;
              return;
        }
        LeaveColor.LblLeave(LblNoeMelk);
    }

    private void LblNoeMelk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HoverColor.LblHover(LblNoeMelk);
        isLabelClicked = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check using a variable to check
check that variable when the unclick event is running.

For example, when the button is clicked, the value of flag becomes 1, and when we unclick, and if the value of flag is 1, it does nothing.

Note:change the value of the flag at the end of the unclick method to 0.